# Different behaviour when using Worksheet object instead of retrieving by name

Tags: vba, excel

Today I have tried to replace using Worksheets("sheet_name") by its name in the VBA editor (Project window) which also matches an object of the same name. For example, I have a sheet with its tab named "STRUCTURE" when viewing in Excel but it's actually named "Saisie" in the VBA editor. In the following code, if you replace `Worksheets("STRUCTURE")` by `Saisie` it should give the same result but the PasteSpecial operation does not paste anything and also does not produce an error message. I have tried using the "Execution" window to check if the proper range was referenced (calling `cell.Address` returns the proper address) and on the proper sheet (calling `Saisie.Name` returns "STRUCTURE").

Is there a difference in semantics between both notations or did I screw up elsewhere ?

Here is the working code with Worksheets("STRUCTURE") which breaks when replacing with `Saisie`.

```
Public Sub ForcerFormules()
    Dim cell As Range, last_row As Range

    Set last_row = Saisie.Range("B65535").End(xlUp).EntireRow

    'Ligne 10 = ligne des titres = saisie vide donc on ignore
    If last_row.Row <> 10 Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

        For Each cell In Worksheets("STRUCTURE").Range("A8:DB8")
            If cell.Formula <> "" Then
                cell.Copy
                Worksheets("STRUCTURE").Range(cell.Offset(3, 0), Intersect(cell.EntireColumn, last_row)).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
            End If
        Next cell

        Worksheets("STRUCTURE").Range("A1").Activate
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I dont see a problem with your code. It works fine for me. Make sure your logic is correct ie. last row in Range("B") is not 10 and row 8 is not empty

Comment: I can't test in Excel 2003 (assuming you're in 2003 based on the 65535 row count...) but this works in 2010 when I test.

Comment: Excel 2007. Bad habit sorry

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur I set up a worksheet and changed the CodeName of sheet1 to Saisie; and the Name to STRUCTURE.  After making the replacement of Saisie for Worksheets("STRUCTURE"), your code did the copy/paste with no problem.  Are you sure you don't have a typo someplace in your substituted code?

Answer (score 0):

If you experiencing a problem then include:

```
Dim Saisie As Worksheet
Set Saisie = Sheets("STRUCTURE")
```

before your

```
Set last_row = Saisie.Range("B65535").End(xlUp).EntireRow
```